# in rails 5 can I connect Microsoft sql server 2008?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

Can I connect Microsoft SQLserver2008 in Rails 5?
after installing the following gems:

- [`gem 'tiny_tds'`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds)
- [`gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter)

while running `rails s`, I am getting this error:

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:26:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError)<br />
>   from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0<br />
>   -x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:26:in`rescue in '
>   from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0
>   -x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:29:in `'

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/
lib/tiny_tds.rb:26:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (Loa
dError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0
-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:26:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0
-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
 GEM FILE 

source 'https://rubygems.org'
 
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
 
 
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
gem 'pry'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
 
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
 
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
 
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
 
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end
 
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
 

C:\Sites\ss_app-master\ss_app-master>rake gem:windows
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds
C:/Sites/ss_app-master/ss_app-master/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)
>'
C:/Sites/ss_app-master/ss_app-master/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2
.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tiny_tds-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/2.3/tiny_t
ds.so
C:/Sites/ss_app-master/ss_app-master/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)
>'
C:/Sites/ss_app-master/ss_app-master/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
 
C:\Sites\ss_app-master\ss_app-master>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the full error backtrace and the content of your Gemfile?

Comment: updated full error and gem file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very beginning I was thinking that your problem was related to the availability of the gem for your current ruby version (something like this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/361)).

Digging into the [documentation of the gem](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#compiling-gems-for-windows), in order to install on win you should run `rake gem:windows` first:

> ## Compiling Gems for Windows
>
> For the convenience of Windows users, TinyTDS ships pre-compiled gems
>   for Ruby 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3 on Windows. In order to generate these
>   gems, rake-compiler-dock is used. This project provides a Docker image
>   with rvm, cross-compilers and a number of different target versions of
>   Ruby.
>
> Run the following rake task to compile the gems for Windows. This will
>   check the availability of Docker (and boot2docker on Windows or OS-X)
>   and will give some advice for download and installation. When docker
>   is running, it will download the docker image (once-only) and start
>   the build:
>
> `$ rake gem:windows`

Comment: while running $ rake gem:windows I m getting errors

Comment: can you install the gem outside the Gemfile (`gem install tiny_tds --platform=ruby`)?

Comment: I m installed by using gem file